# Modelling User Groups in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I'm getting really confused as to how to implement a certain feature in my Rails app - basically, user groups. With one owner and several users of different types. Also, these are temporary, so no data should be stored in the User model proper.

Basically - 1 'owner' user, undefined number of 'type 1' users (each already having the role 'type 1' as an attribute independent of the group), undefined number of 'type 2' users, etc.

E.g. 1 owner, X number of plumbers (each possessing the role 'plumber'), Y number of electricians, Z no. of carpenters, etc.

Sort of like [Modeling User, Group and Membership database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144429/modeling-user-group-and-membership-database-tables), but I'm not able to figure out how to extend it further.

I'm using Rails 5 with ActiveRecord and the gem Rolify for roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work with a `Group` model having the `:owner` via `belongs_to` referencing the `User`.

Then another `GroupUser` model with `belongs_to :group` and `belongs_to :user` and possibly some type column to serve your needs.